# I have a PHP form, how can I give an input field a value of current page_id?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a PHP form where I have a hidden input field. I need it to have a value of current page_id, that goes to my SQL table in a column called page_id.

My images table: `images = image_id, page_id, image_text, image_file;`
My pages table: `pages = page_id, page_name;`

Example of my page URL: `mywebsite/page.php?id=4`

Form (page.php):

```
<form method="POST" action="page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="<?php echo $page['page_id']; ?>">
        <div>
          <input type="file" name="image">
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea 
            id="text" 
            cols="40" 
            rows="4" 
            name="image_text" 
            placeholder="Write something here.."></textarea>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

classes.php file:

```
class Page {
    public function fetch_all(){
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pages");
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }    
    public function fetch_data($page_id) {
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $page_id);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();
    }
}
```

With the code I have right now, it gives me a random page_id=6, no idea where the 6 comes from..

What I want: image page_id = page_id of the page where the image was posted.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is `$page`? Where is it coming from?

Comment: You're not getting the value from the URL you should use a `$_GET` for this instead of `$page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$page` on your form isn't defined.

Use `$_GET` to pull the id from the URL.

Your hidden input should change to the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" />
```